# How to get the Join of Two One to Many associations?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, activerecord, join

I have two hibernate entities User and Blog. User can be interested in multiple Tags. Blog can belong to multiple Tags. For a User, How do i find the Blogs which belong to the Tags the User is interested in?

I need something like

```
Select * from Blog where Blog.Tags IN User.Tags
```

except that SQL or HQL doesnt allow such comparisons in IN clause

A solution which I'm using currently is:

1. Generate a VIEW USER_BLOGS which is the cartesian product of the
   join tables USER_TAGS and BLOG_TAGS.
2. Define an Entity UserBlog for the View and use it to filter Blogs in
   the HQL query:

   ```
   Select * 
   from Blog 
   where Blog.id 
   IN (Select blog_id from UserBlog where user_id = "CurrentUser")
   ```

Im sure this is a common scenario. Is there a pure Hibernate or HQL solution for this?

Comment: How are the relationships between the blog and tags and the user and tags stored?

Comment: in two join tables BLOG_TAGS and USER_TAGS with TAGS on a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
select b.* 
  from blog b 
  join blog_tags bt on bt.blog_id = b.id
  join user_tags ut on ut.tag = bt.tag
  where ut.user_id = (this_user)
```

Contrary to the comment, I believe HQL does permit explicit joins (I may be wrong, but see http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/reference/en/html/queryhql-joins.html).  It could be done without explicit joins, in any case:

```
select b.* 
  from blog b, blog_tags bt, user_tags ut 
  where ut.user_id = (this_user) 
    and bt.blog_id = b.id 
    and ut.tag     = bt.tag
```

Comment: Pretty well summed up in SQL, except that Hibernate doesn't accept Join tables in HQL explicitly.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  See http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/reference/en/html/queryhql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

afair HQL has IN eg. somecat in elements (cat.kittens)

http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

This chapter is purely about queries there is big part about handling collections and joins.
gl hf

Answer (score 0):

For MarkusQ's solution, i had to declare entities for join tables like UserTag and BlogTag to use in HQL query.

My previous solution of creating a USER_BLOGS view was too slow.

This is the HQL query that worked without any additional entities:

```
select b.* from Blog blog, User user, Tag tag
where tag in elements (user.tags)
and tag in elements (blog.tags)
and user.id = (current_user)
```

If you find any problems in this or better solutions, please post your answers